# Create a variable and execute code inside a Sandbox

Tags: javascript

How do I manage it to place variables and run code inside Sandbox() through Run()?

```
function Sandbox() {
    this.test = 'insandbox';
}

Sandbox.prototype.Run = function(src) {
    eval.call(this, src);
};

Sandbox.prototype.getvar = function(name) {
    return this[name];
};

var bx = new Sandbox();
bx.Run('var x = 1;');
print(bx.getvar('test'))
print(bx.getvar('x'))        // undefined
print(x)
```

Please no answers regarding eval() is insecure and I shouldn't use it.
Please no answers regarding the use of setters/getters.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I think you're in the wrong scope

Answer (score 3):

This might not be what you're looking for but what if instead of passing a string to your sandbox you pass a function. This even allows the possibility of using `eval` for source files.

Your code would work like this:

```
...

Sandbox.prototype.Run = function(fn){
    fn.call(this);
}

var bx = new Sandbox();
bx.run(function(){
    this.x = 1;
});
bx.getVar("x") // 1
```

then if you wanted to use `eval` all you would have to is write a function to append the function syntax

```
/* source.js */
this.x = 1;
this.blah = "Hello, World!";
```

With:

```
Sandbox.prototype.evaluate = function(src){
     return eval("function(){" + src + "}");
}

bx.Run(Sandbox.evaluate(src));
bx.getVar("x") // 1
bx.getVar("blah") // "Hello, World!"
```

Also with this method you can pass the sand-boxed code objects and functions to use by passing them to the function which will simulate an entirely new pseudo-environment to work with.

Edit: I did a little research on the **perfect** answer to your question which is

> Can I iterate over the variables declared in a local scope?

And the answer is [no (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600361/javascript-reference-a-functions-local-scope-as-an-object). It looks like it's a limitation of javascript at the moment. Hopefully something like this will emerge in the new spec.

My idea at the moment would be to eval the source to make all the var statements go to the window object which, **with some effort**, could be iterated over and added to the `Sandbox` object manually.

Like this **Warning: horribly simplified**

```
(function(){
    var src = get_source_file();
    eval(src);
    iterate_over_each_newly_created_window_property(function(property, value){
         bx[property] = value;
         window[property] = undefined;
    });
})();
```

Edit 2:
**MY IDEA WORKS =)**

```
function Sandbox(){
    return this;
}
Sandbox.prototype.run = function(src){
    // Take a snapshopt of the window object before
    var before = {};
    var prop;
    for(prop in window){
        before[prop] = true;
    }
    // Then evaluate the source
    window.eval(src);
    // Then see what changed
    var changed = [];
    for(prop in window){
        if(!before[prop]){
            // Add to the sandbox object
            this[prop] = window[prop];
            delete window[prop];
        }
    }
}
var bx = new Sandbox();
bx.run("var x = 'Hello, World!';");
alert(bx.x);
```

[A working example (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/aApPJ/1/)

```
function Sandbox(){
this.keys = [];
this.values = [];
    return this;
}
Sandbox.prototype.eval = function(src){
    var before = {}, prop, fn;
    // Take a snapshopt of the window object before
    src = "function(" + this.keys.join(",") + "){" + src + "}";
    src = src.replace(/var/g, "");
    /* I'm not a wisard at regex so a better one should be used avoid this bug
    var x, y, z; */
    for(prop in window){
        before[prop] = true;
    }
    // Then evaluate the source
    fn = window.eval(src);
    fn.apply(window, this.values);
    // Then see what changed
    for(prop in window){
        if(!before[prop]){
            // Add to the sandbox object
            this.keys.push(prop);
            this.values.push(window[prop]);
            this[prop] = window[prop];
            delete window[prop];
        }
    }
}
var bx = new Sandbox();
bx.eval("var x = 1;");
bx.eval("var y = x;");
alert(bx.x);
alert(bx.y);
```

Edit 3: Fixed bug [to your specifications](http://jsfiddle.net/Joey/LGGCB/1/)

Now I know there are bugs in it and some functions that might make it go haywire. Now it's your job to clean up the code for real use. I gave you conceptually how it can be done.

Comment: This is not what I can use in my situation but thanks for your support!

Comment: No, those variables should be placed inside the Sandbox object.

Comment: This is not that bad! :-) I was just thinking about using with() for that purpose. I will def. look over that approach, perhaps we can fine tune it a bit more. I do not like that window.eval() ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
...

Sandbox.prototype.run = function(src) {
    eval(src);
};

...

bx.run('this.x = 1;');

...
```

Comment: bx.getvar('x') will result in undefined. i would like not to need the use 'this' in the expression for Run().

Comment: You need to use `this` if you want it to work. `var` creates a local variable that's not associated with the instance of `Sandbox`.

Comment: Yes this works. Thank you. But I can not add this to every expression because I don't know what exact kind of expression is used every time for Run().

Comment: But isn't it possible to set a local variable and use getvar() to return the local variable?

Comment: No, the local variable is gone as soon as its scope ends. And that scope is not part of the `getvar` method.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a closure

```
Sandbox.prototype.Run = function(src) {
    (function(_src){
        eval.call(this, _src);
    })(src);
};
```

Comment: eval can only run in the global scope. That's a javascript limitation.