# Javascript/ECMAscript/Spidermonkey: scope vs. this?

Tags: javascript, scope

If I execute the following:

```
var scopes = [];
scopes.push(this);
var x = "123";
function foo() {}

(function () {
   var y = "456";
   function bar() {}
   scopes.push(this);
})();
```

then the `scopes` object contains two identical copies of the global object, and both `foo()` and `x` are defined as properties of the global object.

But `y` and `bar()` are defined in a local scope. Is there any way to obtain a reference to this scope object? If not, is there any way to define an object programmatically within that scope?

for example, in the global scope I can do this:

```
this.wham = "789";
this.baz = function() { return 2; }
var vname = 's';
this[vname] = "Dynamic name!"
```

and I can access them via `wham` and `baz()` and `s`.

If I had an object like this:

```
var obj = {name: 'ha', value: 3};
```

I'm looking for a way to define a variable in a local scope that has the name equal to the contents of `obj.name` and the value equal to the contents of `obj.value`, assuming the variable `obj` is visible in that scope.

Is this possible?

edit: Use case follows --

```
function define_in(scope, name, value)
{
    scope[name] = value;
}

(function() {
   define_in(?????, 'x', "super");
   var y = x + " powered";  // would like to get "super powered"
})();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but to clarify the role of "this": if a function is called as a member function (e.g. obj.test()) then "this" will be assigned the object (obj in my example) for the scope of the function. Otherwise it can be the global object, or if running in strict mode, will likely throw an error.  In short, just because you are in a different bariable scope does not necessarily mean that "this" will refer to the current scope.

Comment: darnit, this is a duplicate. I tried searching for it, I really did.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Reference a functions local scope as an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600361/javascript-reference-a-functions-local-scope-as-an-object)

Answer (score 2):

There's no "local scope" variable.  You'd need make one yourself, unfortunately.

```
(function () {
   var scope = {};
   scope.y = "456";
   scope.bar = function(){};
   scopes.push(scope);
})();
```

Comment: ..or worse use the `evil` function...oops I meant `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a self executing function you could create a function constructor and define object members and/or private members, allowing you to choose what to expose and what not, if that is what you're looking for.