# Hack to attain a reference to a scope?

Tags: javascript

I read somewhere that it is absolutely impossible to attain a reference to a scope. Are there any hacks to get a reference to a scope and 'trap' it inside a variable?

EDIT:

I know I can acquire the global scope through the `window` object. I am referring to dynamically creates scopes of functions and so fourth.

Comment: far too vague a question without examples. scope/closure is not a trivial concept

Comment: Other than a native extension of the JavaScript engines, no. None of the major engines current offer direct exposure of [lexical environments](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2) or [environment records](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.1) to JavaScript code.

Comment: Related: [Reference a functions local scope as an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600361/javascript-reference-a-functions-local-scope-as-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

Refrence to windows object/global scope inside variable can be like this. Here i assume you are in global scope

```
 var reftowindows = this;
```

> I am referring to dynamically creates scopes of functions and so
>   fourth.

Function defined at global scope

```
function returnRefrence(){
var refvar = this;
return this;

}
```

Calling function return variable holding refrence to `window` as scope

```
console.log(returnRefrence()); // console logs "window" object
```

Calling function with call() and binding it to object changes the scope and returns variable holding refrence to `obj` as scope

```
 obj = {};
 console.log(returnRefrence.call(obj)); // console logs "obj" object
```

Comment: `this` won't be the global object in strict mode.