# Access the outer scope's variables via bracket notation

Tags: javascript, closures

Obviously an inner function can access the outer scope's variables, e.g.

```
function example() {
    console.log('My name is ' + name);
}

var name = 'Dave';
example();
```

Is it possible to access that variable with bracket notation? e.g.

```
function example() {
    console.log('My name is ' + outerScope['name']);
}
```

(For those of you wondering why I want to do this, it's for a potential debugging technique, not actual production code).

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Reference a functions local scope as an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600361/javascript-reference-a-functions-local-scope-as-an-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's impossible. Scopes are no objects accessible from JS code, and don't have properties.

You can use `eval` though if you want to access variables by their name with a string. Alternatively, you should check whether your runtime has a debugging API that you could use, it will typically expose such information.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how I'd use `eval` in this case? Such as in my `example()` function above?

Comment: `console.log('My name is ' + eval('name'))` should do (of course it uses normal identifier resolution, you cannot access shadowed variables or variables on a specific scope).

Comment: Great! That achieves what I was aiming for.

Comment: Doing that is terrible though. If you want a bunch of named variables that you access with the variable name in a string: bundle them up as properties of an object.

Comment: @Quentin: Of course it is. I trusted OP to only use this to explore "*a potential debugging technique*".