# calling a function from its string name on Window object

Tags: javascript, window-object

Why is the test fuction declaration not found in the window object? Thanks

```
!function(){
   function test(){
    console.log("testing");
   }   
   var check = window["test"]
   console.log(check); //undefined
 }();
```

Comment: Because `test` is not in the window object? You've created a closure, that's kind of the point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `function test()` is local to the scope of the toplevel function expression, it's not bound to `window`, the global scope. You can refer to it as a local variable:

```
!function() {
    function test() {
        console.log('testing')
    }
    console.log(test)
}()
```

Or bind it directly to `window` for a global variable:

```
!function() {
    window.test = function test() {
        console.log('testing')
    }
    var check = window['test']
    console.log(check)
}()
```

You cannot access the local scope as a variable - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600361/javascript-reference-a-functions-local-scope-as-an-object) for more details.