# Why doesn't binding a prop work but using an arrow function does?

Tags: react-native, react-functional-component

I want to create a login page where an error message is displayed when fields are empty. I use function components, state and props to keep the UI separated from the logic. So I have a `UserSignInController` which returns a `UserSignInView` which gets displayed on screen.

When I set a `onPress` callback for the login button, it calls `onClickCheckLogin()` in the controller. But setting the error message only works if I use an arrow function as a prop, if I use `.bind(this)` it doesn't.

This works
`UserSignInController.js:`

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Linking, Alert } from 'react-native';
import UserSignInView from './UserSignInView';
import User from '../../User';

const renderSignInView = () =>
{
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  return (
      <UserSignInView
          errorMessage = {errorMessage}
          setUsername = {setUsername}
          setPassword = {setPassword}
          //arrow function passing the state to onClickCheckLogin
          checkLogin = {() => { onClickCheckLogin(username, password, setErrorMessage)}}
          openPrivacyPolicy = {onClickOpenPrivacyPolicy}
      />
  )
};

const onClickCheckLogin = (username, password, setMessageFunction) =>
{
    if(!! username && !! password)
    {
      console.log("yeee");
    }else 
    {
      console.log('doooo');
      setMessageFunction('Username/password empty');
    } 
};
```

This does not work `UserSignInController.js:`

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Linking, Alert } from 'react-native';
import UserSignInView from './UserSignInView';
import User from '../../User';

const renderSignInView = () =>
{
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  //bind function instead of arrow function
  onClickCheckLoginCallback = onClickCheckLogin.bind(this);

  return (
      <UserSignInView
          errorMessage = {errorMessage}
          setUsername = {setUsername}
          setPassword = {setPassword}
          //use the binded version
          checkLogin = {onClickCheckLoginCallback}
          openPrivacyPolicy = {onClickOpenPrivacyPolicy}
      />
  )
};

const onClickCheckLogin = () =>
{
    if(!! this.username && !! this.password)
    {
      console.log("yeee");
    }else 
    {
      console.log('doooo');
      this.setErrorMessage('Username/password empty');
    } 
};
```

With this I get an error `TypeError: _this.setErrorMessage is not a function. (In '_this.setErrorMessage('Username/password empty')', '_this.setErrorMessage' is undefined)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2600401/12461184). You can't access local properties of a function from the outside. That `globalObject` displayed with `console.log` is just the window object. So, binding with `.bind()` can't work. As an alternative, you may pass the `setErrorMessage` property as an argument, and also the username and password.

I wrote on a separate answer to better distinguish from the first one

Comment: Then I'm confused as to what `bind(this)` does when used in functional components in React-Native. Since I thought that would bind the called function to the parent context (with properties, especially with `state` properties). I will use your suggestion as that was what I had and what worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that `renderSignInView` is defined as an arrow function itself. The `this` keyword is not pointing to the component then, so calling `setErrorMessage` results in an error. Try changing to the following:

```
function renderSignInView(){
//Component
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't help. I also changed `onClickCheckLogin` to your suggestion but I still get the same error.

Comment: Try logging the `this` property

Comment: Could you tell me how? I can only get `[Object]` `[object GlobalObject]` or `JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures` when I log it to the console using `.toString()` or something like that.